# Thumbnails when mouseovering on progress bar of a video

Tags: html, video, web, thumbnails

I am very new to HTML5 . I want a similar feature for my video as given in the link http://demo.jwplayer.com/text-tracks/thumbs.html  (when i mouseover on progressing bar , it should give me the thumbnails image) . I followed all the steps given in Link https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/08/building-interactive-html5-videos/

I am getting the following error in my console (Inspect element).
I am also using .vtt file and images.

**Text track from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading: Not at same origin as the document, and parent of track element does not have a 'crossorigin' attribute. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**

Your comments to solve the issue will be highly helpful .

Thanks

Comment: are you loading your video/webpage over http://, if so then the vtt file can't point to a file:// reference (has to use same protocol, and be on same domain as the html page)

Comment: I am not using http protocol . The file is in local system. i am using file://..  to render the webpage . @Offbeatmammal

Comment: hmm. just had a quick try and in my test if I was serving content over file it won't work, but over http it did work. you may need to host (even on a local server) the page to test

Comment: Thnaks @Offbeatmamma . It worked on local server .

Comment: Did you find a way ? :)